# How to paraphrase "not to mention"

Tags: paraphrasing

Is the use of "not to mention getting a promotion" in the following sentence natual? If not, how to rewrite it? The main idea is: working hard is a must to have a job, getting a promotion needs to work even harder.

> It is a hard fact that only diligent employees who devote the majority
>   of their time and energy on sharping professional skills can get
>   themselves employed, not to mention getting a promotion

Comment: The sentence is not very natural. There is a mixup of formal and colloquial terms and grammatical constructions are off. It's a mistake to try to write motivational text before mastering the details.

Comment: It's not that bad, don't get discouraged. I think *sharpening their professional skills* would make the register more consistent, and grammatically it should be *to sharpening* not *on sharpening*, because of *devote*. I also think that *let alone promoted* would make the grammar neater. Your *can... getting a promotion* doesn't really work. Kate Bunting corrects it to *get*, but you could also consider dropping it altogether and letting the first *get* run on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is natural. Another way to say it is *let alone get a promotion*. The sense is  that getting a job is difficult enough in itself, before you even start to think about getting promoted.